# How to draw a separator-line between two middle columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table containing 4 columns, something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| first name   last name   first name   last name |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Now I want this:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| first name   last name | first name   last name |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
        <td>first name</td>
        <td>last name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, as you see, two columns on the right are exactly the same with two columns on the left. Now I want to draw a separator-line between them, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the second `td` element and set a right border for it. It can also be achieved using left border of third td element.

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
td {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first name</td>
    <td>last name</td>
    <td>first name</td>
    <td>last name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, `:nth-child` works on old browsers as well. http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Can you please take a loot at my update? I think you can give me a solution (something similar current solution just horizontally)

Comment: Would you mind rolling back the update and posting that as a new question? This is because the edit is not related to the title. It is better to be posted as a new question so other users may benefit and you don't get a down vote.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but I can not ask a new question after at least 1 next hour. anyway ok tnx.